# Surcharges that were not invoiced

Tags: if-not-exists

I have a table named INVOICES. I want to select all the invoice numbers where a certain charge code is missing.
I kindly ask your help to help me out with this. All I need is something like :

```
Select * from Invoices where (Invoices.chargecode="FREIGHT" is not present)
```

An invoice can have many charge lines but all I need to know is all those invoices user forgot to charge "FREIGHT" which cannot happen.

Many thanks.
Paul

Comment: Please add your table schema and tag your RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work for you? Assuming Invoices has an ID column which you can replace in this code:

```
SELECT * FROM Invoices WHERE InvoiceID NOT IN
(SELECT InvoiceID FROM Invoices WHERE chargecode = 'FREIGHT')
```

Comment: Why would you need to do a select distinct on the where clause, seems like it is doing extra filtering that is not needed.

Comment: You're right. Just a habit to avoid the multiple values in subqueries error. But not needed here.

Comment: Jacob H , many thanks it worked on perfection. It is always nice when a rookie gets such valuable help. You did contribute to increase my knowledge :)

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.